# gcc: Optimize single function with `-mavx -mprefer-avx128`

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, avx

I want to optimize a single function with `-mavx -mprefer-avx128`. Basically none of the code shall use AVX, except for one of the functions: This one should use AVX128.

I tried these things:

```
__attribute__((target("avx")))
void f() { ... }
```

=> seems to use avx2

```
__attribute__((target("prefer-avx128")))
void f() { ... }
```

=> does not compile

```
__attribute__((target("avx")))
__attribute__((optimize("prefer-avx128")))
void f() { ... }
```

=> does not compile

Maybe someone knows how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-mprefer-avx128`, and it's modern replacement `-mprefer-vector-width=128`, are `-m` options, not `-f`, so they can only possibly work with `target("string")` rather than `optimize("string")` attributes.

But actually only some `-m` options work as attributes; the [GCC manual's list of x86 target attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html#index-target-function-attribute-5) is mostly ISA extensions, `arch=` and `tune=`, but also includes `prefer-vector-width=OPT`.  There isn't one based on the older option `-mprefer-avx128`; probably support for an attribute was added after `-mprefer-avx128` was obsoleted in favour of the `-mprefer-vector-width` option.

```
__attribute__((target("avx,prefer-vector-width=128")))
```

That enables AVX (AVX1 only, not AVX2), and tunes for 128-bit auto-vectorization.  Since integer code is easier to auto-vectorize, I actually tested with AVX2:

```
__attribute__((target("avx2,prefer-vector-width=128")))
unsigned foo(unsigned *arr){
    unsigned sum=0;
    for(int i=0 ; i<10240; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

__attribute__((target("avx2")))
unsigned bar(unsigned *arr){
    unsigned sum=0;
    for(int i=0 ; i<10240; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Compiled with `gcc -O3 -mtune=haswell` ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27__attribute__((target(%22avx2,prefer-vector-width%3D128%22)))%0Aunsigned+foo(unsigned+*arr)%7B%0A++++unsigned+sum%3D0%3B%0A++++for(int+i%3D0+%3B+i%3C10240%3B+i%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++++++sum+%2B%3D+arr%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+sum%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A__attribute__((target(%22avx2%22)))%0Aunsigned+bar(unsigned+*arr)%7B%0A++++unsigned+sum%3D0%3B%0A++++for(int+i%3D0+%3B+i%3C10240%3B+i%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++++++sum+%2B%3D+arr%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+sum%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-mtune%3Dhaswell%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+9.0.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)), the first version uses `vpaddd xmm`, the second uses `vpaddd ymm`.  (tune=haswell sets the normal vector-width preference to 256.)

---

**Terminology**: AVX1 supports 256-bit vector width for FP operations like `vaddps`.
AVX2 is 256-bit integer operations like `vpaddb ymm`, and lane-crossing shuffles with granularity finer than 128-bit like `vpermps` / `vpermq`.

`__attribute__((target("avx")))` will definitely not use AVX2 instructions if you didn't already enable them on the command line or with an earlier `#pragma GCC target`

Answer (score 2):

The option you are looking for is `__attribute__((target("prefer-vector-width=128")))` -- see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html#x86-Function-Attributes for other options.

```
__attribute__((target("prefer-vector-width=128")))
__attribute__((target("avx")))
void f1(float* restrict x, float const* y) { 
    for(int i=0; i<16; ++i)
    {
        x[i] += y[i];
    }
}
```

Godbolt-Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/f3xWY3vs6